# Delete and save duplicate in another file

Tags: python

In test.txt:

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   a
5   d
6   c
```

I want to remove duplicate and save the rest in test2.txt:

```
2   b
5   d
```

I tried to start with the codes below.

```
file1 = open('../test.txt').read().split('\n')
#file2 = open('../test2.txt', "w")
word = set()
for line in file1:
    if line:
        sline = line.split('\t')
        if sline[1] not in word:
            print sline[0], sline[1]              
            word.add(sline[1])
#file2.close()
```

The results from the codes showed:

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
5   d
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The issue with your code is that the first time any letter is encountered it will not already be in the word set, and so not be considered a duplicate. You need to take two passes over your list as shown in Ashwini's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `collections.Orderedict` here:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
with open('abc') as f:
    dic = OrderedDict()
    for line in f:
        v,k = line.split()
        dic.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
```

Now `dic` looks like:

```
OrderedDict([('a', ['1', '4']), ('b', ['2']), ('c', ['3', '6']), ('d', ['5'])])
```

Now we only need those keys which contain only 1 items in the list.

```
for k,v in dic.iteritems():
    if len(v) == 1:          
        print v[0],k
...         
2 b
5 d
```

Comment: @ThanaDaray Use the `Ordered Dictionary` recipe for py2.6 and earlier. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693-ordered-dictionary-for-py24/

Comment: @ThanaDaray simply replace the `print` statement with `file.write`.

Comment: I adapt your codes. It said "ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack" Any suggestion?

Comment: @ThanaDaray your text contains empty files, handle them.

Comment: @ThanaDaray use `if line.strip()`:

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is that you're just making sure every second item (letter) gets printed out only once. Which obviously is not what you're saying you want.

You must split your code into two halfs - reading and gathering statistics about letter counts, and part which prints only those which has `count == 1`.

Converting your original code (I just made it a little simpler):

```
file1 = open('../test.txt')
words = {}
for line in file1:
    if line:
        line_num, letter = line.split('\t')
        if letter not in words:
            words[letter] = [1, line_num]
        else:
            words[letter][0] += 1

for letter, (count, line_num) in words.iteritems():
    if count == 1:
        print line_num, letter
```

Comment: +1. To simplify, use a `defaultdict` with the `default_factory` set to `int`

Comment: 1_CR: wouldn't work because I'm storing list with two values in the dictionary and the second item in that list (`line_num`) changes for every row. I agree that it could be written using `defaultdict`, but it would be more complicated and I wanted to keep it simple, stupid

Answer (score 1):

I tried to keep it as similar to your stlye as possible:

```
file1 = open('../test.txt').read().split('\n')

word = set()
test = []
duplicate = []
sin_duple = []
num_lines = 0;
num_duplicates = 0;
for line in file1:
    if line:
        sline = line.split('   ')
        test.append("   ".join([sline[0], sline[1]]))
        if (sline[1] not in word):
            word.add(sline[1])
            num_lines = num_lines + 1;
        else:
            sin_duple.append(sline[1])
            duplicate.append("   ".join([sline[0], sline[1]]))
            num_lines = num_lines + 1;
            num_duplicates = num_duplicates + 1;

for i in range (0,num_lines+1):
    for item in test:
        for j in range(0, num_duplicates):
            #print((str(i) + "   " + str(sin_duple[j])))
            if item == (str(i) + "   " + str(sin_duple[j])):
                test.remove(item)


file2 = open("../test2.txt", 'w')
for item in test:
    file2.write("%s\n" % item)
file2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about some Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("test_remove_dupl.txt",sep=",")

b = a.drop_duplicates(cols="a")
```